# method that tells if there is some text written in the text-field?

Tags: java, textfield

Is there any predefined method that tells whether or not text field contains some text ?

Comment: This definitely falls under the purview of RTFM.

Comment: There wouldn't be much point to a text file if you couldn't get the text out of it.

Answer (score 4):

Use `getText().isEmpty()` on your TextField.

Answer (score 2):

`!(textfield.getText().equals(""));` will tell you if there is some text.